# How to show math symbols in a web application using Appcelerator titanium?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, mathml

I am making a web application for iphone and Android where I have to show the math symbols. At first I used mathML, but it is not working for some symbols. My question is that "What is the alternative to show the math symbol in webkit/mobile web browser". Can anyone suggest me what will be the better option to go with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) javascript library? It will automatically convert TeX and MathML snippets to pictures on the client side. It's the same that is used by for example [math.stackexchange.com](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions). Here is a [demo page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/) to try it out too.

[It supports all major browsers and devices](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/browser-compatibility/).